# Grouping components but with duplicate function

Tags: components, grouping, c++builder

I would like to group a bunch of components(TEdits, TCombobox, etc) together so that if I have an "add" button, when I press it I can duplicate everything inside that grouping of components. I looked at TGroupBox but it doesn't look like it has a duplicate function, or mb i missed it. if no such component how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new `TFrame` class at design-time (`File > New > Frame` or `File > New > Other > C++Builder Projects > C++Builder Files > VCL Frame`, depending on your version) and put whatever components you want on it.  Then at run-time, you can create new instances of that class when needed.

Comment: i am in the process of trying this out. i got all my components in a TFrame...and I saved it. How would a go about creating a new instance of that class in my main form? sorry it's my first co-op term still trying to get use to all these terms

Comment: You create it with the `new` operator like any other dynamically allocated class, eg: `TMyFrame *frm = new TMyFrame(this); frm->Parent = this; ...`.

Comment: ahhh ty! you answered my next question as well. i was just looking at how to set the frame's parent